# Getting derivative of each pixel in image

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to calculate and store the derivatives of each pixel `(i,j)` of an image using `▽xf(i,j) = f(i,j)- f(i, j-1)` at each pixel location, my problem is I'm having trouble implementing this in Matlab.

What I'm doing is loading an image, converting it to double from unsigned integer, initialising `Dxf` with zeroes and then attempting to get the derivatives of each pixel for every `(i,j)`:

```
InputImage = imread([DataDir,'kodim09gray.png']); 

InputImage = double(InputImage);

[IHeight,IWidth] = size(InputImage);
Dxf = zeros(IHeight,IWidth);

for i = 1:IHeight
    for j = 1:IWidth
        Dxf(i,j) = InputImage(i,j) - InputImage(i,j-1);
    end
end
```

Unfortunately I get the following indexing error:

```
Attempted to access InputImage(1,0); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in GetXDerivative (line 13)
        Dxf(i,j) = InputImage(i,j) - InputImage(i,j-1);
```

I can see what's causing the issue as `InputImage(1,0)` can't exist, but I still can't think of how to resolve this without ruining the calculation needed at each pixel.

Comment: As you already realized, you won't be able to get the left differential quotient of the first column. How about filling it with `NaN`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this. Here are two:

```
n = size(InputImage,1);
%// Method 1
Dxf = [nan(n,1), diff(InputImage,1,2)]
%// Method 2
Dxf = [nan(n,1), conv2(InputImage,[1,-1],'valid')]
```

---

A quick fix for your code would be to start your loop at `2`:

```
for j = 2:IWidth
```

You will however have zeros in your first column, which are not correct, as they should be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide what it means to take the derivative at the edge of an image. Typically `f'` can only be defined where `f` is continuous. Consider `f(x) = |x|`. The derivatives at `x=1` and `x=-19584` are defined but not at `x=0`. The edge of the image is similarly not continuous as `j=0` does not exist.

I would think the best option would be to make `Dxf` smaller in the x direction so definitions exist for all pixels. Similarly, the range of `DDxf` would be even smaller.

Alternatively, you could decide that `Dxf(1,1)` should be white or black.

Comment: Hm. To be mathematically precise, continuity is not enough. `abs` is continuous at zero, just not continuously differentiable. It is not really about continuity there, but rather about a left-differential quotient being used.